# Should "const" be used semantically or syntactically?

Tags: c++, constants

```
class A
{
    ...

    public:
        shared_ptr<Logger> GimmeLogger () const
        {
            return m_logger;
        }

    private:
        shared_ptr<Logger> m_logger;
};
```

**In `class A`, should `GimmeLogger` be `const` or non-`const`?**

It would make sense to be `const` because it is a simple getter that doesn't modify `*this` (syntactic `const`).

But on the other hand, it returns a non-`const` pointer to another object that it owns (semantically non-`const`).

Comment: Could `m_logger` be `shared_ptr<Logger const>` instead?

Comment: Scott Mayers book (Effective C++) Item 21 has an interesting discussion on `const`. It is a book well worth reading if you are programming C++. Basically the upshot is use `const` whereever possible and use the wiggle room.

Comment: Are you asking about loggers in particular, or "owned" objects in general? Without getting too deep into the concept of monads from functional programming, it's probably reasonable for you to consider a logger to be something into which data is thrown without really changing its state. As such, there's no reason that you shouldn't use a logger belonging to a const object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make that non-const, then you cannot write this:

```
void f(const A & a)
{
    auto v = a.GimmeLogger(); //error
}
```

So if you want to write this; that is, if you want to call `GimmeLogger` on const object, then make `GimmeLogger` a const member function, because you cannot invoke a non-const member function, on const object. However, you can invoke a const member function, on non-const object (as well as on const object).

Inside a const member function, every member is semantically const objects. So the type of `m_logger` in the function becomes `const share_ptr<const m_logger>`.  So change the return type accordingly.

Comment: *uh..."The party of the first part shall be known in this contract as the party of the first part."* --from "A Night at the Opera"

Answer (score 2):

Because `const` is a keyword, it is checked *syntactically*, but it should be used *semantically*, that is, in your design operations that don't change the visible state of your class should be marked as `const`.

That is the whole idea behind the `mutable` keyword: adding the ability to mark a member as *this does not take part of the visible state of the object* so that the syntactic check matches the semantic meaning. In your particular case, because you are *copying* a pointer, you don't even need to use `mutable` there (this is one of the weak points of const-correctness actually, as returning a non-const pointer does not trigger errors while compiling, even though you are opening a door for changes in your object)

In this particular case, on the other hand, I don't see a good reason by which the object would publicize it's logger... That is, const-correctness aside, why do you need to grant access to the logger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be `const`.  The `const`-ness of the function has nothing to do with the `const`-ness of the return type.

I get your point, but I think the function remains `const` either way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you shouldn't return a handle to a member data when you can avoid it. Try hard to review your design and find a way around this. That said, if you must, it should be `const`. This allows you to call the function on `const` objects as well as non-const objects. See for example `std::string::c_str()`. You can also overload the function so you get both, like standard containers do with iterators.

When in doubt, look in the standard library for a hint.